# withdrawal of funds from smart contract

Tags: solidity

I put this code which I found at a website to transfer funds from my deployed smart contract back into my metamask wallet.  I pasted it into my code, and it worked fine in my Remix with a fake account. I deployed the contract with this code included, and funded the smart contract with some ETH and when I clicked on withdrawMoney, it printed 0 ETH and it sent nothing to my wallet. Why didn't it send me the full balance in the contract back to my metamask wallet?

```
unction getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
}

function withdrawMoney() public {
    address payable to = payable(msg.sender);
    to.transfer(getBalance());
}
```

Comment: check the etherscan to see if someone withdrawed before you.
this function could easily got sniped

Comment: This code was a scam. I learnt this from watching a video on youtube regarding MEV bots. While the culprits address is not readily apparent in the code, it is in fact concatenated with numerous returns.  I'm out $1200 which I'll never recover.

Comment: did you send ETH or WETH? wrapped ETH is an ERC20 token and can't be transferred back this way. Also note that this code is extremely  unsecure, anyone can run withdrawMoney and drain the contract, not just the owner.